# How to reformulate this UX question?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I keep reading in several ux.stackexchange.com answers and comments like:

"This question does not belong here, it belongs to"...

Lets take [this example](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57362/logo-size-for-new-website):

> Logo size for new website?

So, I believe there can be good UX answers for this question, but, some members replied like:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about branding. It belongs on Graphic Design.SE who have a Branding tag

Which I also believe, he's got a point.

I decided to post this example in order to discuss how can the question itself be reformulated in order to belong as a total UX question.

Answer (score 2):

For that particular question - as it is written it's not really ideally suited to this site. There isn't really a correct answer to 'what size should a logo be' in the context that it has been asked. And even if there were a correct answer it isn't a User Experience issue that the Original Poster is having. Whatever option they choose isn't going significantly impact the experience of the user. They are asking the question from a Branding / Marketing point-of-view - they want the logo to be memorable and usable elsewhere.

If the question were refocused around the User *Experience* aspect - how the presentation of the logo will impact how users access and bond with the application that would be different. But at present it is really 'how small can I make my logo so that it is still memorable'. That's a branding and marketing issue, not a UX one.

A UX issue would possibly be something like: "Is it more important for users to see the company logo when visiting the app in order to get reassurance and confidence that the site they've visited is legitimate or should the priority be on the search field because that's what users are coming to the site to do?".

But even then it's a bit subjective and more of a poll than a question so may not be ideal either. But at least it's more on the topic of User Experience.